My Tracking Folder in SFMC
I would like to use the reports provided in SFMC however I cannot see any of my journey sends under My Tracking folder so I cannot run any report.
Is there a way to get them there? 

You wont find the journey builder send under Mytracking. However, you can find the journey builder report under tracking > report > journey builder send

If you want to run the journey builder report daily then I would suggest using Analytic Builder > Rpeorts > run Journey Builder Email Send Summary


Thank you , I want to run the email performance by domain report for my journey send but it only lets me select the folder My Tracking

Why not use intelligence reporting and create a report with this information?

Thanks everyone
